# How to run query as a string using Gremlin Python

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I'm using lambda to query a Neptune graph where I'm trying to get output paths for a set of nodes. The query string is dynamically created in code as shown below. I was initially using `Eval()` to do this but on further research I see that Eval() comes with alot of issues so I wanted to know how I query a Neptune db with a string query?

```
for n in node_lst:
    database_url = "wss://neptune-db:8182/gremlin"
    connec = DriverRemoteConnection(
        database_url, "g",
message_serializer=serializer.GraphSONSerializersV2d0(),
transport_factory=lambda:AiohttpTransport(call_from_event_loop=True)
    )

    g = traversal().withRemote(conn)
    query_str = "g.with_('evaluationTimeout',50000).V(n).emit().times(max_hops).path().toList()"
    query_result = str(eval(query_str))
    conn.close()
    // Process graph output
```

I see from other posts here that there is a way to have the query as a string using `client.submit()` using [this](https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/basic-client.py) code but from what I understand we need to create a websocket connection to a locally running Gremlin Server. In this case, the server does not run locally.

I also tried with a local Gremlin Server but I get the below errors:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'source_instructions'
```

```
Failed to interpret Gremlin query: Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 2, error message : no viable alternative at input 'g.with_'"
```

I'm not able to find documentation regarding this. Could someone please help on how I could query Neptune using a string?

Comment: Try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/quickstart-python

Answer (score 0):

The Gremlin Python client can send queries either as byte code or as text, either way, it uses a web socket connection.  However, if you are going to send the query as text you would not use `DriverRemoteConnection` you would instead use the `Client` class. Please see the example below.

```py
from gremlin_python.driver import client

def create_client(endpoint):
    conn = client.Client(endpoint,'g')
    return conn
            
def run_query(conn, query):
    result = conn.submit(query)
    future_results = result.all()
    return future_results.result()

conn = create_client(endpoint)
query = 'g.V().limit(1)'
results = run_query(conn, query)
```

Comment: So by "endpoint" you mean the Neptune DB endpoint name that we see on the AWS console right? Because when I replace "endpoint" with the what I see on the console, I get a `InvalidURL` error. I also tried using "wss://endpoint:8182/gremlin" but received a `Failed to interpret Gremlin query: Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 2, error message : no viable alternative at input \'g.with_\'`  error message. (Sorry if I'm missing something, I'm new to Neptune and gremlin so I'm trying to figure things out as I go)

Comment: Since you are using string query you don't need to use python escaping for special keywords such as "with". Instead of "with_" use "with". 
Change the string query to : "g.with('evaluationTimeout',50000).V('{}').emit().times({}).path().toList()".format(n,max_hops)

Comment: and just to confirm that yes, the endpoint should be in the `wss://endpoint:8182/gremlin` form.

Comment: This worked, thanks!
Also we don't have to specify "g" here right? My understanding is that since here we are using client to connect we don't have to specify "g = traversal().withRemote(conn)" as we would do when using DriverRemoteConnection. Is that correct? Or am I understanding this wrong?